# Is there something wrong with my print statement?

Tags: python

I have to enter a `diameter`, then change it to a float, and after divide the `diameter` by 2. The beginning of my code works, but when I coded, `print (radius)` it stopped working. Maybe I made a mistake?

```
diameter = float(input("Enter a diameter:  "))
print(diameter)

#changing diameter to type float

myfloat = diameter

#creating a variable name radius
# assign radius the value og diameter/2

radius = (diameter/2)   # this where it went wrong

print = "The radius is equal to"  
print(radius)
```

I keep getting, `'str' object is not callable`

Comment: You shouldn't assign value to `print`. Don't use `python` builtin names for variable names. And then you are trying to call it in the next line `print(radius)`, which is what causing the issue. You're shadowing the `print`

Comment: I tried that, but it keeps saying, "'str' object is not callable"

Comment: to display text you need `print("The radius is equal to")` instead of `print = "..."`

Answer (score 4):

Python is a dynamically typed language, which means you can reassign almost anything, *including* the builtin `print` function.

When you do ...

```
print = "The radius is equal to"
```

... you're setting the value of `print` to a `str`, which isn't callable. Instead, just use some other name, like `foo`:

```
foo = "The radius is equal to"
print(foo)
print(radius)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this was very helpful! But it's not doing the math, do you happen to know why?

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I can tell, the math looks fine.

Comment: @mackorone, You didn't print radius in the end.

Comment: Oh, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to assign `print` to your string instead of printing it. That made print a variable, not a function as far as the code was concerned. Here is the working code.

```
diameter = float(input("Enter a diameter: "))
print(diameter)
myfloat = diameter
radius = (diameter/2)
print("The radius is equal to")
print(radius)
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much! this really helped me

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. If you think that mine is the best answer, click the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in you code is you are assigning a `string` value to an existing method `print`. In `python` you can reassign any any value to anything, since `python` is one of the 'Dynamically typed languages'. So, `print` became a `string` variable. Now, what you are doing is calling `print` like a method with `()` , so `print` which is of type `str`, is not a method so you cannot call like that, that is why you are getting the error `'str' object is not callable`.

Try the following:

```py
diameter = float(input("Enter a diameter: "))
print (diameter)
radius = (diameter/2)
print("The radius is equal to : ", radius)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to rewrite your code. Hope you don't mind. If you still don't understand how to use the str() function, maybe this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cvM-crlDvg

'''This is creating a variable that takes user input.
the float is there just as a precaution, if they include a decimal'''
num = float(input('Enter a number: '))

'''Then type the equation.'''
radius = num/2

'''To print this, notice how I use a "str()" function. this makes it
so that you can add numbers to strings.'''
print('The radius is ' + str(radius))
'''                      ^
                         | This is vital. program wont work without it.

'''